# Autocomplete select event not triggering every time

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

My latest issue is that a) I can't figure out how to use jqueryui autocomplete to allow me to scroll up and down the options that are presented, sample code would be great (I've tried `autoFocus: true`) but the great problem is that my select event fires one in every 10 times or so, even if I put an alert it there it seems quite random. Currently I've only been able to even try selecting using the mouse event for reason a).

The latest code I've been trying to get it working with is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#message").autocomplete({ 

        dataType: 'json',
        source: function(request, response){

            var str = $("#message").val();
            var atindex = str.lastIndexOf('@');
            if (atindex != -1 && str.length-atindex > 1) {
                str = str.substring(atindex+1);

                var spaceindex = str.indexOf(' ');
                var lastname = ''
                if (spaceindex != -1){
                    lastname = str.substring(spaceindex+1);
                 // if (lastname.indexOf(' ') != -1){lastname = lastname.slice(0,lastname.indexOf(' '));}
                    str = str.slice(0,str.indexOf(' '))+ ' ' + lastname;
                }

            $.post("utilities/atuser.php", {data: str}, function(data){

                $("#suggestions").show();
                //$("#usersuggest").html(data);
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                var test = new Array();
                response($.map(json, function(item){

                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value,
                    }

                    })
                    );

                }); }


            }, 
        appendTo: "#usersuggest" ,

        autoFocus: true,



    }); 


    $( "#message" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) { 
             $("#message").attr("value",ui.item.label);
             $("#usersuggest").focus();
             return false;
});

    $( "#message" ).bind( "autocompleteopen", function(event, ui) { 
             $("#usersuggest").focus();
});





    } );
```

Thanks!
Shaananc

**EDIT:** In regards to issue a) Key up and key down now scroll between values in the textbox, rather than highlighting the options in the list that appears, is there anyway to change this behavior? However, using the scroll up and down the values that get entered are correct, where as if I click to select I get the following code instead appear in the box: `*<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Test Name</a>*`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ ?
This seems to have the scrolling through the options as you wanted.

Comment: When I tried to adapt it to my page, as above, with the custom source function things seems to break :( !